# Python dataframe - count occurrences based on day of the month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
In []: df.head()
Out [] : 
DATE          NAME       AMOUNT     CURRENCY
2018-07-27    John       100        USD
2018-06-25    Jane       150        GBP
...
```

The contents under the DATE column are of date type.

I want to aggregate all the data to be able to see to understand the days of the month and the count of the number of transactions that happened on that date.

I also wanted to group it by year as well as day.
The end result I wanted would have looked something like this

```
YEAR     DAY       COUNT
2018     1         0
         2         1
         3         0
         4         0
         5         3
         6         4
and so on
```

I used the following code but the numbers are all wrong. Please help

```
In []: df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE':pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2018,7,27),end=dt.datetime(2020,7,21))})
       df.groupby([df['DATE'].dt.year, df['DATE'].dt.day]).agg({'count'})
```

Comment: why do you think it's wrong? `df[df["DATE"].dt.year==2019].groupby([df['DATE'].dt.year, df['DATE'].dt.day]).agg({'count'})` returns 12 for days 1-28, 11 for 29&30 and 7 for 31.  Exactly as I would expect

Comment: Doesn't work. I manually verified it with the data but its all wrong

Comment: not sure how you are concluding it's wrong `df[df["DATE"].dt.year==2019].groupby([df['DATE'].dt.year, df['DATE'].dt.day]).agg({'count'}).reset_index(drop=True).sum()
` returns 365 which is correct

Comment: Worked with this code 
`df.groupby([df['DATE'].dt.year.rename('year'), df['DATE'].dt.day.rename('day')]).agg({'count'})`